# What is the reference source for a standard XUnit report XML

Tags: xml, unit-testing, xunit

I am writing an alternative to CUnit and i want it to generate XML output.

I want the output to be compatible to jenkins / hudson - so i am looking for the standard xml form that all XUnit tests complie to.

Is there such a standard?

Where is the definition of requirements to be displayable by jenkins/hudson?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://reflex.gforge.inria.fr/xunit.html#xunitReport